# Heroku Scheduler with Custom Intervals using "simple_scheduler"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, roo-gem

I want run an scheduler at every saturday at 11.45pm, But if use **whenever** gem it will not support in heroku, How can we write Heroku Scheduler with Custom Intervals?

Answer:

Simple Scheduler is a scheduling add-on that is designed to be used with Sidekiq and Heroku Scheduler.It gives you the ability to schedule tasks at any interval without adding a clock process. Heroku Scheduler only allows you to schedule tasks every 10 minutes, every hour, or every day.

STEP 1: gem "simple_scheduler"
STEP 2: bundle
STEP 3: Create the file config/simple_scheduler.yml in your Rails project:

```
# Global configuration options. These can also be set on each task.
queue_ahead: 360 # Number of minutes to queue jobs into the future
tz: nil # The application time zone will be used by default if not set

# Runs once every 2 minutes
simple_task:
  class: "SomeActiveJob"
  every: "2.minutes"

# Runs once every day at 4:00 AM. The job will expire after 23 hours, which means the
# job will not run if 23 hours passes (server downtime) before the job is actually run
overnight_task:
  class: "SomeSidekiqWorker"
  every: "1.day"
  at: "4:00"
  expires_after: "23.hours"

# Runs once every half hour, starting on the 30 min mark
half_hour_task:
  class: "HalfHourTask"
  every: "30.minutes"
  at: "*:30"

# Runs once every week on Saturdays at 12:00 AM
weekly_task:
  class: "WeeklyJob"
  every: "1.week"
  at: "Sat 0:00"
  tz: "America/New_York"
```

STEP 4: Add the rake task to Heroku Scheduler and set it to run every 10 minutes: **rake simple_scheduler**

For more information you can follow below link,

https://github.com/simplymadeapps/simple_scheduler

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved. Say we have a task named example_task, we can do this:

```
example_task:
  class: "ExampleJob"
  every: "1.week"
  at: "Sat 23:45"
```

Note that `ExampleJob` has to extend `ActiveJob::Base` and implement the perform method which will hold the logic for your task.